# Google Maps Javascript API: infowindow opens at same position, although multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I set up a map with multiple markers using Google Maps Javascript API. If a marker is clicked, an infowindow opens. However, while the content is correct (different for each marker), the infowindow opens above one and the same marker, no matter which one is clicked.

To fix this, I tried to explicitly set the correct position (long/lat) in the eventlistener function. According to console log output, the values for long and lat are correct. But the infowindows still opens at the wrong, identical position.

Here is the code; placeMarker is called from within a loop through all locations:

```js
   var activeInfoWindow;  

    function placeMarker(map, lat, lng, markerurl, title, contentString) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
              icon: markerurl,
              map: map,        
              title: title,              
            });  
                                    
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });            
            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {   
            
                // close other active infowindows
                if (activeInfoWindow) { 
                    activeInfoWindow.set("marker", null);
                    activeInfoWindow.close();
                }
                
                // added to explicitly set new position:
                infowindow.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
                
                // check: console log shows on click: lat and long correct (different for each clicked marker)
                console.log(lat+' '+lng+' '+title);
                
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                activeInfoWindow = infowindow;                                            
            });      
    }
```

Any idea what I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Simply needed to add "var" before "marker":

```js
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
              icon: markerurl,
              map: map,        
              title: title,              
            });
```